# How to condition a point process to the actual sampling data?

Tags: point-process

**Figure A** demonstrates a point process (object=rectangle) with marks as the length and width of the rectangle. **Figure B** shows a realization of the point process regarding the information extracted from the input data.
The **question** is:
How to condition (using pre-conditioning or post-conditioning) the realization to the existing data points with marks?

[image]

**More Explanation:**
Figure **E** demonstrates point process which has location, and width and height marks added.
Figure **A** is our point process. Figure **B** added marks as width and height variables. Figure **C** is our realization of the point process by means of information extracted from Figure **A**. Figure **D** is final marked point process, a realization.
We seek a method to condition this realization to Figure **B**.
[image]

Comment: Can you clarify this?  I don't understand the setup or the question.

Comment: More explanation was added.

Comment: I don't understand: "Figure A is our point process". Looks like Figure A is a realization of a point process.  Then "Figure C is our realization of the point process by means of information extracted from Figure A." I don't understand that either. By "realization of a point process", do you mean a sample from a point process?

Comment: Well. It is correct. Fig A is a realization of pp. Fig C is another realization of that pp. How to condition Fig C to Fig A? and How to condition Fig D to Fig B?

Comment: What does it mean to "condition" one realization of a point process to another?